# Updating Data in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and not sure how to get my plot data and how to update it.
My code is following these instructions:
https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Bokeh-Python-Visualization/blob/master/interactive/exploration/interactive_development.ipynb

But unfurtunately the update method doesn't seem to work for me. i was trying to find documentation regarding this method but couldn't find any. can anyone assist?
basically i've generated a pandas dataframe from my data and converted it to ColumnDataSource. now i want to add or subtract data from it but the new ColumnDataSource does not update the old one.

Any help would be most appreciated! This is my code as of now, it still won't update properly:

```
def update(attr, old, new):
    stations_to_plot = [int(station_selection.labels[i]) for i in station_selection.active]
    by_station = pd.DataFrame(data=no_bikes.loc[stations_to_plot,:'23 PM'].values,index=list(map(str,initial_stations))
                          ,columns=no_bikes.loc[:,:'23 PM'].columns.tolist())
    new_src = ColumnDataSource(by_station.T)
    r.data_source.data.update(new_src.data)


stations=list(map(str,no_bikes.loc[:,'station_avg'].nlargest(10).index.tolist()))
station_selection = CheckboxGroup(labels=stations, active = [0,1,3])
station_selection.on_change('active', update)

initial_stations = [int(station_selection.labels[i]) for i in station_selection.active]   
range_select = RangeSlider(start = 0, end = 23, value = (0, 23),step = 1, title = 'Hours to plot')
range_select.on_change('value', update)

by_station = pd.DataFrame(data=no_bikes.loc[initial_stations,:'23 PM'].values,index=list(map(str,initial_stations))
                          ,columns=no_bikes.loc[:,:'23 PM'].columns.tolist())

src = ColumnDataSource(by_station.T)

p = figure(plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500, title = 'Chances not to find bikes',
                       x_axis_label = 'Hour of the day', y_axis_label = 'Proportion',x_range=src.data['index'])

for i,station in enumerate(src.data.keys()):
    if station in list(map(str, initial_stations)):
        r=p.line(x='index',y=station,source =src, legend='Station N.'+station, color=Category20_16[i], line_width=5)




controls = WidgetBox(station_selection,range_select)
layout = row(controls, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Is `src` a global variable? Could you provide a minimal example? [`from_df`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.from_df) may be useful if you are using a DataFrame to update the data

Comment: @ChesuCR i've updated my code into the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meant a minimal "working" example haha, `no_bikes` is not defined. Anyway, you also tried to update the source directly, right? `src.data = new_src.data` Keep in mind that you are iterating over the stations in the loop and you are overriding the `r` variable. You should use a list if you want to store all the renderers, if not you will get only the last one: `r.append(p.line... )`